# Optimization problem with Mahalanobis distance

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus, mahalanobis-distance

This question is a follow-up of one of my previous questions:
[Optimizing a vector equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534967/optimizing-a-vector-equation)

Let $x$ and $b$ be two vectors of real numbers in k dimensional space.

Let $W$ be a k-by-k matrix of real numbers representing a transformation.

Let $\alpha$ be a scalar value.

We are looking for the optimal alpha, which minimizes the squared Mahalanobis distance between x and the multivariate distribution, $ N(b, \Sigma) $ scaled by $\alpha$:

$$ D = (x - \alpha b)^T (\alpha W)^{-1} (x - \alpha b) $$

The Mahalanobis distance:

$$ D = (x - \mu) \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu) $$

As it can be seen, in our case, $\mu = \alpha b$ and $\Sigma = \alpha W$

I took the derivative of the Mahalanobis distance, according to [Differentiating mahalanobis distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623097/differentiating-mahalanobis-distance) and applied the chain rule to get to $\alpha$:

$$ \eqalign { 
\frac {dD} {d \alpha} &= \frac {dD} {d \mu} \frac {d \mu} {d \alpha} + \frac {dD} {d \Sigma} \frac {d \Sigma} {d \alpha} \cr
&= -2 \Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu) b - \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu) (x - \mu) \Sigma^{-1} W \cr
&= 0 \cr
2 \Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu) b &= -\Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu) (x - \mu) \Sigma^{-1} W}$$

This expression is reduced by multipliing by $\Sigma$ from the left and by expanding the $\Sigma^{-1}$ term on the rightmost side, getting

$$ 2 (x - \mu) b = - (x - \mu) (x - \mu) \alpha^{-1} $$

Expanding the $\mu$ terms on both sides and expanding the parentheses yields

$$ \eqalign {
2xb - 2 \alpha bb &= -(xx - 2 \alpha xb + \alpha^2 bb) \alpha^{-1} \cr
2xb - 2 \alpha bb &= -\alpha^{-1}xx + 2xb - \alpha bb}$$

This can be simplified by adding $2xb + \alpha bb$ to both sides and multipliing by -1 getting

$$ \eqalign {
\alpha bb &=  \alpha^{-1} xx \cr
\alpha &= \sqrt { \frac {||x||^2} {||b||^2} } \cr
\alpha &= \frac {||x||} {||b||}}$$

I have the strong intuition that I went wrong somewhere. Could someone please check my calculations?

Comment: I think your intuition that something went wrong is correct for the simple reason that your result does not depend on $W^{-1}$. Instead of doing such complicated calculations, you should try to develop the first expression that you have for $D$ and then work from there. As a side note you forgot a transpose in your second expression for $D$ (and in the subsequent equations).

Comment: For the chain rule you need to use $$\frac{dD}{d\alpha} = \frac{\partial D}{\partial\mu}:\frac{d\mu}{d\alpha} + \frac{\partial D}{\partial\Sigma}:\frac{d\Sigma}{d\alpha}$$ where the colons denote the trace product, i.e. $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question though: is this trace product equivalent to the hadamard (or entrywise) product? Maybe followed by a summation?

Comment: Yes, you can think of the trace product as a hadamard product followed by a sum over all the elements. Written with explicit summations it looks like this $$A:B=\sum_i\sum_k A_{ik}B_{ik}$$

Comment: Why $\alpha W$ in $D$ instead of (constant) $W$ ? Consider all scalars, 1d, with $W =1$ and $\alpha \to 0$ .

Comment: Because we are morphing a normal distribution along the line defined by (0, 0), $b$. Not only its center moves, but the shape given by $W$ also changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use the product notation (:) for the trace, i.e. 
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
For convenience, let's define new scalar, vector and matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
 \beta &= \alpha^{-1} &\implies d\beta=-\beta^2d\alpha \cr
 z &= \alpha b-x &\implies dz=b\,d\alpha \cr
 M &= W^{-1} &\implies \beta M=(\alpha W)^{-1} \cr
}$$
Now we can find the differential and gradient of the distance directly
$$\eqalign{
 D &= \beta M:zz^T \cr
dD
 &= \beta M:d(zz^T) + d\beta\,M:zz^T \cr
 &= 2\beta M:(dz\,z^T) - \beta^2M:zz^T\,d\alpha \cr
 &= (2\beta Mz:b - \beta^2M:zz^T)\,d\alpha \cr
\frac{\partial D}{\partial\alpha}
 &= 2\beta Mz:b - \beta^2M:zz^T \cr
 &= 2\beta b^TMz - \beta^2z^TMz \cr
}$$
Set the gradient to zero, and multiply by $\alpha^2$ 
$$\eqalign{
2\alpha b^TMz &= z^TMz \cr
2\alpha b^TM(\alpha b-x) &= (\alpha b-x)^TM(\alpha b-x) \cr
2\alpha^2 b^TMb - 2\alpha b^TMx &= \alpha^2b^TMb -2\alpha b^TMx + x^TMx \cr
\alpha^2 b^TMb &= x^TMx \cr
}$$
Yielding this expression for the optimal parameter value
$$\eqalign{
\alpha^2 &= \frac{x^TW^{-1}x}{b^TW^{-1}b} \cr\cr
}$$
Although it was not stated, I assumed that $W$ is symmetric.

Comment: OK, the real problem has a bit more complication in it and to solve it, I'm trying to internalize your calculation, but I can't seem to be able to look up on one sorcery you used. Where do I obtain the powers to do such magic: $dD = \beta M : d(zz^t) + d \beta M : zz^T $ ? This is not simple derivation, you are only obtaining differentials somehow. Does this technique have a name by which I can look it up and read about it?

Comment: Well, it's not magic. The product rule for differentials $$d(A\star B) = dA\star B + A\star dB$$ holds for any type of product, whether its the Kronecker or Hadamard or Schur or Trace or Frobenius or Matrix or Dyadic or Dot or Double-Dot or Triple-Dot product.$$ $$Further, the operands $(A, B)$ can be scalars, vectors, matrices, or tensors -- whatever makes sense for the product under consideration.

Comment: Yes, but you are doing arithmetic on differentials, I thought differentiation, e.g. $ \frac {df} {dx} $ should not be treated as a quotient, but as a symbol as a whole.